# after installing tinker, laravel webapp shows error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5* framework. Everything had worked fine so far until I installed tinker vendor to the project. Now I have following error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::__construct() must be an instance of Laravel\Lumen\Application, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\Laradmin\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\helpers.php on line 240 and defined
```

I am a new so do not have any idea about the error. How can I solve it? thanks

Comment: What package did you install? Did you add the service provider to `app.php`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using laravel and not lumen?

Comment: I have installed following packages :

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.7.0",
        "zizaco/entrust": "^1.8",
        "vluzrmos/tinker": "^1.3"

Comment: Guessing her,run `php artisan vendor:publish` and then restart your server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vluzrmos/tinker` package is meant to add tinker to Lumen. It looks as if you are using Laravel 5.3, which already has tinker built in. There is no need for that package, and is causing you issues because it is pulling in the `lumen-framework` as a dependency.

Remove the `vluzrmos/tinker` package and use the Laravel built in tinker command (`php artisan tinker`).